# How to set future/old date to post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have posts in WordPress which belong to category 13,
I want to replace the date of the post to  future or old date.

example I have post news which was created on 31/12/2012, I want to replace this date to 01/01/2014 how can I do that ?

what functions in WordPress can help me, or does this belong to PhpMyAdmin?
I will be glad to get direction on how to solve this problem

many thanks for any help.

I found this code:

```
function bulk_schedule_posts_wpse_105834() {
  $args = (
    array(
      'cat' => 1,
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_status' => 'draft',
      'post_type' => 'post',
    )
  );
  $posts = new WP_Query($args);
  if (!$posts->have_posts()) return false;

  $date = '2013-08-01';
  $times = array(
    '10:00',
    '14:00',
    '17:00',
    '20:30'
  );

  while ($posts->have_posts()) {

    global $post;
    $posts->the_post();

    if (0 !== $posts->current_post && 0 === $posts->current_post%4) {
      $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 day',strtotime($date)));
    }

    $thisdate = $date.' '.$times[$posts->current_post%4].':00';
    $date_gmt = get_gmt_from_date($thisdate);
    $post->edit_date = true;
    $post->post_date = $thisdate;
    $post->post_date_gmt = $date_gmt;
    $post->post_status = 'future';

    wp_update_post($post);
  }
}
bulk_schedule_posts_wpse_105834();
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, the field your thinking of (post_date) is both for 'future' & 'past' Furthermore, that functionality of changing it, is on the edit post page, any plugin or function would be doing something that's already there

Comment: this is related to phpmyadmin i guess...if you have small set of data

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is a coding issue, you can set the date of any post in wordpress from the admin panel - you should see the option just before you publish or update.

[image]

And yes you could change the date of a post from the 'wp_posts' table via phpMyAdmin if you really had to.

[image]

Comment: yes you right but I need to do that not manualy i have sevral post and it should be dinamic automatic by function

Comment: Dosen't look like you can bulk update the 'date' from the admin panel yet. your question isn't very clear.

Comment: I want to publish the post now not in future, this make order in my post and delete old post like calnder